# Getting changed variable value of injected class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to shutdown Azure webjobs gracefully in .Net Core. Now I made a class called GracefulShutdown as shown below. I registered this class as singleton. in program.cs I start the webjob using this class. In my job I get this same class to check if shutdown is requested or not. But the value I get is always false. I think there is some multi thread thing going on here, but I am no sure. What am I doing wrong?

Program.cs

```
...
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IGracefulShutdown, GracefulShutdown>();
...
var gracefulShutdown = serviceProvider.GetService<IGracefulShutdown>();
...
gracefulShutdown.StartJob(config);
```

GracefulShutdown.cs

```
public class GracefulShutdown : IGracefulShutdown
{
    private bool gracefulShutdown;

    public bool CheckGracefulShutdownStatus()
    {
        return gracefulShutdown;
    }

    public void StartJob(JobHostConfiguration configuration)
    {
        using (var jobHost = new JobHost(configuration))
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            WebJobsShutdownWatcher watcher = new WebJobsShutdownWatcher();
            gracefulShutdown = false;

            Task.Run(() => {
                jobHost.Start();
                while (!gracefulShutdown)
                {
                    if (watcher.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        gracefulShutdown = true;
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
                    }
                }
            }, watcher.Token).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

ProcessorJob.cs

```
...
private readonly IGracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown;
...
public ProcessorJob(IGracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown)
{
   this.gracefulShutdown = gracefulShutdown;
}
...
if (gracefulShutdown.CheckGracefulShutdownStatus())
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: Multi-threading is hard. Your `gracefulShutdown` should at least be [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) to prevent the processor from optimizing the `while` loop to prevent re-reading the value over-and-over again. But instead, you should use `CancellationToken`, as it is designed to communicate cancellation across threads.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for my singleton to have different values is that the serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider() was called twice in program.cs.
Offcourse this is not needed and after refactor the code works.

Also I changed the Boolean variable gracefulShutdown to a property.